# Links being activated when scrolling on touch screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, scroll, touch

I'm building a scrollable navigation panel for a project, and I'm having some issues optimising it for touch screens. I'm using this piece of script in order to use a touch event where necessary:

```
var getUserInputMethod = function() {

    //same issues using touchend too
    clickEvent = (Modernizr.touch) ? 'touchstart':'click'; 
    return clickEvent;
}

$('#navigation li').on(clickEvent, function() {
    $('#mainContent').load($(this).data('link'));
});
```

However, I can't seem to scroll without selecting a link. Is there a way I can determine between a click/tap and a scroll?